# Qt line causes strange error: Cmd.exe exited with code -20

Tags: c++, qt, qchart, adtf

I am building my project on 2 different PCs, both using the same methods (Visual Studio 2017 with CMake). They both configure and generate fine using CMake. The issue is when I try to build them, one builds fine and the other has errors.

I have isolated the cause of this error and it seems to be whenever I try to instantiate either QLineSeries or QChart. There are NO red squiggles underneath my code. It all looks fine, until I try to instantiate either and then those errors appear.

I use QLineSeries a lot (I have 3 series), and I slowly commented out code until I found the culprit. The first line, me trying to create `lineRedSeries = new QLineSeries;` results in the errors below. Also, even if I comment out everything and try to create `QChart *chart = new QChart();`, it also causes the same errors.

Curiously enough, just declaring QLineSeries and QChartView in my h file doesn't cause this issue (so if I comment out the code in my cpp file). It's only when I try to create a QLineSeries or QChart that the errors occur.

I have removed a lot of unnecessary functions that are not pertinent for this question as my cpp file is quite long.

In my `main.h`:

```
#include <QtCharts> // for QLineSeries, QChartView, Chart
#include <QChartView>

class ExampleProject
{
public:
    ExampleProject();
    ~ExampleProject();

private:
    int OpenGraphic();

private:
    QLineSeries *lineRedSeries, *lineGreenSeries, *lineBlueSeries;
    QChartView *chartView;
};
```

In my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <iostream>

int ExampleProject::OpenGraphic()
{
    char *myargv[1];
    int myargc = 1;
    myargv[0] = strdup("");

    // First, create QApplication
    QApplication a(myargc, myargv);

    // Create our lineChart Series
    lineRedSeries = new QLineSeries; // The most FIRST line and causes errors!
    lineRedSeries->setName("RedSeries");
    lineRedSeries->setColor(Qt::red);
    lineRedSeries->append(1, 20);
    lineRedSeries->append(2, 30);
    lineRedSeries->append(3, 44);

    lineGreenSeries = new QLineSeries;
    lineGreenSeries->setName("GreenSeries");
    lineGreenSeries->setColor(Qt::green);
    lineGreenSeries->append(1, 10);
    lineGreenSeries->append(2, -9);
    lineGreenSeries->append(3, 20);
    lineGreenSeries->append(10, -40);

    lineBlueSeries = new QLineSeries;
    lineBlueSeries->setName("BlueSeries");
    lineBlueSeries->setColor(Qt::blue);
    lineBlueSeries->append(1, -20);
    lineBlueSeries->append(2, -10);
    lineBlueSeries->append(3, 0);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->setTitle("Acceleration Graph");
    chart->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

    // Add series to chart
    chart->addSeries(lineRedSeries);
    chart->addSeries(lineGreenSeries);
    chart->addSeries(lineBlueSeries);
    
    // Customize axes for chart
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).back()->setRange(0, 131);
    chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).back()->setRange(-50, 50);
    chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).back()->setTitleText("Time [s]");
    chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).back()->setTitleText("Acceleration [m/s]");

    // Create chartView
    chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    
    // Render everything within our Window
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    mainWindow.resize(400, 300);
    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code will result in these errors:

```
the argument to a feature-test macro must be a simple identifier, qcompilerdetection.h, Line 1349
the argument to a feature-test macro must be a simple identifier, qcompilerdetection.h, Line 1351
"cmd.exe" exited with code -20, Microsoft.CppCommon.targets, Line 209
```

Complete build output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Automatic MOC and UIC for target main
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Path/To/Drive/src/main/CMakeLists.txt
2>mocs_compilation.cpp
2>main.cpp
2>C:\Path\To\Drive\src\main\main.cpp(132): warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\string.h(536): note: see declaration of 'strdup'
2>   Creating library C:/Path/To/Drive/build/src/main/Debug/main.lib and object C:/Path/To/Drive/build/src/main/Debug/main.exp
2>easy_profilerd.lib(block.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(block.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>easy_profilerd.lib(easy_socket.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(easy_socket.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>easy_profilerd.lib(event_trace_win.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(event_trace_win.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>easy_profilerd.lib(nonscoped_block.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(nonscoped_block.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>easy_profilerd.lib(profile_manager.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(profile_manager.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>easy_profilerd.lib(thread_storage.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'easy_profiler.pdb' was not found with 'easy_profilerd.lib(thread_storage.obj)' or at 'C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\easy_profiler.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>main.vcxproj -> C:\Path\To\Drive\build\src\main\Debug\main.adtfplugin
2>-- Installing: C:/Path/To/Drive/base/tools/adtf/addons/Training/bin/debug/main.adtfplugin
2>-- Installing: C:/Path/To/Drive/base/tools/adtf/addons/Training/bin/debug/main.pdb
2>Done building project "main.vcxproj".
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: main_pdgen, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Generating Debug/main.plugindescription
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_core.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_core.adtfplugin" (Build Type: Debug) [runtime.cpp(1895)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "session_manager.service.adtf.cid". ( 1 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "rpc_object_registry.service.adtf.cid". ( 2 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "core_sample_stream_tracer.service.adtf.cid". ( 3 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [DUMP]: Registered plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_core.adtfplugin", plugins in registry: 2 [runtime.cpp(1422)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\default_core_objects.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\default_core_objects.adtfplugin" (Build Type: Debug) [runtime.cpp(1895)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "default_sample_stream.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 4 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "default_thread_runner.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 5 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "default_timer_runner.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 6 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "default_binding_proxy.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 7 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "sample_stream_merger.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 8 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "substream_selector.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 9 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "substream_assembler.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 10 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "substream_merger.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 11 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "substream_dissector.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 12 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "thread_mapper.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 13 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "thread_invoker.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 14 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "thread_reducer.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 15 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [DUMP]: Registered plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\default_core_objects.adtfplugin", plugins in registry: 3 [runtime.cpp(1422)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_media_description.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_media_description.adtfplugin" (Build Type: Debug) [runtime.cpp(1895)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "media_description.service.adtf.cid". ( 16 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [DUMP]: Registered plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_media_description.adtfplugin", plugins in registry: 4 [runtime.cpp(1422)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_kernel.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_kernel.adtfplugin" (Build Type: Debug) [runtime.cpp(1895)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [ERROR]: Could not register plugin in runtime Result code '-20 '(ERR_NOT_FOUND) - Could not load plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\addons\addons-toolbox\bin\debug\main.adtfplugin": file or dependencies not found [File: c:\j\workspace\dtf-builder_release_3.11.1_lucky\repo\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1825] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::LoadPluginImpl]
3> [File: c:\j\workspace\dtf-builder_release_3.11.1_lucky\repo\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1359] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::RegisterPlugin] [main.cpp(161)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [ERROR]: Result code '-20 '(ERR_NOT_FOUND) - Could not load plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\addons\addons-toolbox\bin\debug\main.adtfplugin": file or dependencies not found [File: c:\j\workspace\dtf-builder_release_3.11.1_lucky\repo\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1825] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::LoadPluginImpl]
3> [File: c:\j\workspace\dtf-builder_release_3.11.1_lucky\repo\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1359] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::RegisterPlugin] [main.cpp(703)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "kernel.service.adtf.cid". ( 17 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [DUMP]: Registered plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_kernel.adtfplugin", plugins in registry: 5 [runtime.cpp(1422)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_clock.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_clock.adtfplugin" (Build Type: Debug) [runtime.cpp(1895)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]:     Registered class "reference_clock.service.adtf.cid". ( 18 ) [runtime.cpp(2182)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [DUMP]: Registered plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\bin\debug\adtf_clock.adtfplugin", plugins in registry: 6 [runtime.cpp(1422)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:12 [INFO]: Using settings from:C:/Path/To/Drive/AppData\Local\Digitalwerk\ADTF-Configuration-Editor_3.11.1\adtf_configuration_editor.cesettings [main.cpp(601)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [DUMP]: Will increase runlevel to "RL_System" [runtime.cpp(715)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Started UCOM runtime [runtime.cpp(1063)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Switched main clock to 'adtf'. [clock_srv.cpp(353)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Switched stream clock to 'adtf_stream'. [clock_srv.cpp(392)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initializing service "reference_clock.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(765)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: No RPC Object Registry available to register clock for RPC calls [clock_srv.cpp(173)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initialized service "reference_clock.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(796)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initializing service "kernel.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(765)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initialized service "kernel.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(796)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initializing service "media_description.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(765)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Initialized service "media_description.services.adtf" [runtime.cpp(796)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Try to load "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\addons\addons-toolbox\bin\debug\main.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1788)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Deinit all services, filter, streamingservices [main.cpp(325)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "reference_clock.service.adtf.cid". ( 17 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "kernel.service.adtf.cid". ( 16 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "media_description.service.adtf.cid". ( 15 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "thread_reducer.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 14 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "thread_invoker.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 13 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "thread_mapper.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 12 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "substream_dissector.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 11 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "substream_merger.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 10 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "substream_assembler.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 9 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "substream_selector.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 8 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "sample_stream_merger.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 7 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "default_binding_proxy.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 6 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "default_timer_runner.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 5 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "default_thread_runner.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 4 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "default_sample_stream.streaming.adtf.cid". ( 3 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "core_sample_stream_tracer.service.adtf.cid". ( 2 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "rpc_object_registry.service.adtf.cid". ( 1 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]:     Unregistered class "session_manager.service.adtf.cid". ( 0 ) [runtime.cpp(2226)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Unloading plugin: "ADTF Clock Service Plugin" [runtime.cpp(1904)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Unloading plugin: "ADTF Kernel Service Plugin" [runtime.cpp(1904)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Unloading plugin: "ADTF Media Description Service Plugin" [runtime.cpp(1904)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Unloading plugin: "ADTF Default Core Objects Plugin" [runtime.cpp(1904)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Unloading plugin: "ADTF Session Manager Plugin" [runtime.cpp(1904)]
3>2021-09-02 12:44:17 [INFO]: Stopped UCOM runtime [runtime.cpp(1093)]
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -20.
3>Done building project "main_pdgen.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In qcompilerdetection.h, it refers to lines 1349 and 1351 specifically:
[image]

I have included the proper Additional Include Directories within C/C++ > General and the correct .lib files in Linker > Input in VS. My includes are also correct. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: When asking about build-errors, always copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question itself. There might be other hints or informational notes that could help see what happens.

Comment: The actual error seems to be ***2021-09-02 12:44:17 [ERROR]: Could not register plugin in runtime Result code '-20 '(ERR_NOT_FOUND) - Could not load plugin "C:\Path\To\Drive\base\tools\adtf\addons\addons-toolbox\bin\debug\main.adtfplugin": file or dependencies not found [File: c:\j\workspace\dtf-builder_release_3.11.1_lucky\repo\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1825] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::LoadPluginImpl]***

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Okay thank you for your input! I have edited the question and added the entire build output. The only thing I did change was the path names as I was worried it would expose too much information to the public. :D

Comment: @drescherjm The strange thing about that is that I checked that folder and it **does exist.** This is using ADTF.

Comment: I added a tag for that. I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I was missing some very important Qt .dll files in the directory where my ADTF plugins resided. Once I moved the core .dlls (Qt5Charts.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dl, etc.) to the right directory as well as adding this 1-liner:

```
QCoreApplication:addLibraryPath("C:/Users/Path/To/Qt/msvc2017_64/plugins"); // this
```

to right before I instantiate my QApplication, it worked!

Comment: As mentioned in my other answer you are violating the GPL license of QtCharts by using together with ADTF. Thats the reason why ADTF does not deliver GPL content of Qt. I also described you a legal workaround. But I am not your lawyer  technically your solution is working but illegal. So up to you, just for your knowledge. You are also violating your ADTF license agreement by infecting your combinded work with GPL content.

Comment: @C-3PFLO Thank you for your answer, I will fix my project.

Answer (score 1):

ADTF does not deploy QtCharts binaries because the license is incompatible. Qt is basically LGPL licenesed which works fine with ADTF license. But some components are licensed under GPL, QtCharts is one of it. You are not allowed to use QtCharts with ADTF because then you violate the combined work rule described within GPL. GPL is not working with commercial and closed source licenses, only with open source GPL compatible licenses  like GPL itself, MPL or others. Anyway, because the binary is missing you are getting the error, that some dependencies are missing. But even when you put the binary there, it is not allowed, neither private nor commercial. Its incompatible and thats why ADTF tries to protect the customer and delivers only LGPL content. You even not allowed to use commercial Qt with ADTF using open source Qt because Qt declines mixing oss with commercial license even thats the same binary (politics...). Only chance, buy qtcharts standalone from qt marketplace then its compatible with LGPL. But you have to put the binary yourself. Or you link static, which is allowed with commercial/marketplace license from Qt.